# Python loop through Url Range

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

The script below should go to 3 different pages and write all three of those to a csv. However it is only writing the last page. If I `print(my_data)` it also only print the last page. What that is telling me is it is not the write to csv which is the error but within the `for i in range(41244,41246)`.

Here is my code:

```
import base64
import requests
import json
import csv

USERNAME, PASSWORD = 'admin', 'admin'

for i in range(41244,41246):
    req = requests.get(
        url="https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nhl/2017-2018-regular/game_startinglineup.json?gameid=" + str(i)
        , 
        headers={
            "Authorization": "Basic " +
                    base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(USERNAME,PASSWORD)\
                                    .encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
        }
     )
req.raise_for_status()
data = req.json()
my_data =[]

for i in range(2):
    EX_team_home = data['gamestartinglineup']['teamLineup'][i]['expected']['starter']

for i in range(1):
    EX_team_away = data['gamestartinglineup']['teamLineup'][i]['expected']['starter']

for i in range(20):
    EX_homepos = EX_team_home[i]['position']
    EX_awaypos = EX_team_away[i]['position']
    EX_homename = EX_team_home[i]['player']['LastName']
    EX_awayname = EX_team_away[i]['player']['LastName']

    my_data.append([EX_homepos, EX_homename, EX_awaypos, EX_awayname])

print(my_data)

header = ["EX_homepos", "EX_homename", "EX_awaypos", "EX_awayname"]

with open("TESTLINE3.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(my_data)
    f.close()
```

`EX_homepos EX_homename     EX_awaypos      EX_awayname
Goalie-Backup   Hutton      Goalie-Backup   Budaj
ForwardLine1-RW Sobotka     ForwardLine1-RW Kucherov
ForwardLine2-C  Schenn      ForwardLine2-C  Johnson
ForwardLine4-C  Brodziak    ForwardLine4-C  Bournival
ForwardLine3-LW Paajarvi    ForwardLine3-LW Palat
ForwardLine4-RW Thorburn    ForwardLine4-RW Paquette
ForwardLine3-C  Sundqvist   ForwardLine3-C  Point
ForwardLine3-RW Thompson    ForwardLine3-RW Gourde
ForwardLine1-C  Stastny     ForwardLine1-C  Stamkos
ForwardLine1-LW Tarasenko   ForwardLine1-LW Namestnikov
ForwardLine2-LW Schwartz    ForwardLine2-LW Killorn
ForwardLine4-LW Upshall     ForwardLine4-LW Kunitz
DefensePair3-L  Bortuzzo    DefensePair3-L  Sustr
DefensePair1-L  Edmundson   DefensePair1-L  Girardi
DefensePair2-R  Parayko     DefensePair2-R  Sergachev
DefensePair3-R  Dunn        DefensePair3-R  Coburn
ForwardLine2-RW Jaskin      ForwardLine2-RW Callahan
DefensePair1-R  Pietrangelo DefensePair1-R  Hedman
DefensePair2-L  Gunnarsson  DefensePair2-L  Stralman
Goalie-Starter  Allen       Goalie-Starter  Vasilevskiy`

There should be another 2 lineups that come out but I am either over writing them or my range is not functioning. No errors occur just not the results expected.

EDIT AFTER SUGGESTION:

```
import base64
import requests
import json
import csv

USERNAME, PASSWORD = 'Name', 'Pass'

header = ["Update", "EX_homepos", "EX_homename", "EX_awaypos", "EX_awayname"]
headers={
            "Authorization": "Basic " +
                    base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(USERNAME,PASSWORD)\
                                    .encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
        }

with open("TESTNNEW2.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    for i in range(41244,41246):
        req = requests.get(url="https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nhl/2017-2018-regular/game_startinglineup.json?gameid=" + str(i) , headers=headers)
        req.raise_for_status()
        data = req.json()

        my_data =[]
        for i in data:
            Update = data['gamestartinglineup']['lastUpdatedOn']

            for i in range(2):
                EX_team_home = data['gamestartinglineup']['teamLineup'][i]['expected']['starter']

            for i in range(1):
                EX_team_away = data['gamestartinglineup']['teamLineup'][i]['expected']['starter']

            for i in range(20):
                EX_homepos = EX_team_home[i]['position']
                EX_awaypos = EX_team_away[i]['position']
                EX_homename = EX_team_home[i]['player']['LastName']
                EX_awayname = EX_team_away[i]['player']['LastName']

                my_data.append([Update, EX_homepos, EX_homename, EX_awaypos, EX_awayname])

                print(my_data)
                writer.writerows(my_data)
```

Comment: Your code using the request is outside of the loop...

Comment: your indentions are incorrect - most of code should be inside `for i in range(41244,41246):`

Comment: Also, the range end is not included, so it's not getting 3 pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring all but the last request by not indenting the code into the loop

I suggest you rewrite the code to open the CSV first, though. You can make a request, parse it, then write the row. There's no benefit to keeping a list of data around for all previous requests

For example

```
header = ["Updated", "EX_homepos", "EX_homename", "EX_awaypos", "EX_awayname"]
headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " +
                base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(USERNAME,PASSWORD)\
                                .encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
    }

with open("TESTLINE3.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    for gameid in range(41244,41247):
        req = requests.get(url="https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nhl/2017-2018-regular/game_startinglineup.json?gameid=" + str(gameid) , headers=headers)
        req.raise_for_status()
        data = req.json()
        staring_lineup = data['gamestartinglineup']

        update = staring_lineup['lastUpdatedOn']
        team_away = staring_lineup['teamLineup'][0]['expected']['starter']
        team_home = staring_lineup['teamLineup'][1]['expected']['starter']

        for i in range(20):
            home_player_name = team_home[i]['player']['LastName']
            home_player_pos = team_home[i]['position']

            away_player_name = team_away[i]['player']['LastName']
            away_player_pos = team_away[i]['position']                

            writer.writerow([update, home_player_pos, home_player_name, away_player_pos, away_player_name])
```

And you don't need close the file when you use `with` to open the file

Comment: I edited the code per your suggestion and still get the same output. See EDIT AFTER SUGGESTION: above. If possible please copy full code and edit in your answer for better understanding on my end.

Comment: Your `for i in data:` is still not indented on the same level where you defined `data`

Comment: Ok, i got the indent now, thanks. Problem now is it loops through way too many times.

Comment: `(len(range(41244,41246)) == 2) == True`

Comment: Print the values of your loop variables. Test the code in smaller portions.

Comment: Thanks for editing your code. Just tried for about 30 mins before I noticed it. Just not structured properly at all. Thanks for taking the time!